# How to save an already-saved INDD file for use with an InDesign one version earlier?

Tags: save-as, adobe-indesign

I have created 30 files with my 2019 InDesign version and for some reasons I am reverting back to InDesign 2018 and need those files opened there. So, I have not yet uninstalled InDesign version 2019. I want to be able to get to the Save File window which I can specify the version of the InDesign the file will be used with.

Currently, when I choose "Save as" I only have the option to save as a 2019 InDesign Document (INDD) or (IDMT for CS4 or later - which I don't want).

Thank you-

Comment: Why not save in IDMT format, at least temporarily?

Comment: Will the file be fully editable?

Comment: It has been years since I last used InDesign. But I suppose that you can always re-save it as INDD. You can try it with your own InDesign, since apart from the format change I think the 2018/2019 versions should be almost identical.

Comment: I don't have a recent version as older ones do everything I need, but can't you save as IDML?

Comment: Well, I am looking for an answer.

Answer (score -3):

Copy all of those 30 files and test save as InDesign version 2019 and one in CS4 or later and try to open them in InDesign 2018. 
If you have another PC to test it that's perfect. Install InDesign 2018 and try it in another PC.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. I mentioned on the question that the 2019 file doesn't work on 2018 and cs4 lacks some features of my files.